# Python : Create a dataframe from existing pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Now, my dataset looks like this:

```
tconst  Actor1  Actor2  Actor3  Actor4  Actor5  Actor6  Actor7  Actor8  Actor9  Actor10
0   tt0000001   NaN GreaterEuropean, WestEuropean, French   GreaterEuropean, British    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   tt0000002   NaN GreaterEuropean, WestEuropean, French   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   tt0000003   NaN GreaterEuropean, WestEuropean, French   GreaterEuropean, WestEuropean, French   GreaterEuropean, WestEuropean, French   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   tt0000004   NaN GreaterEuropean, WestEuropean, French   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   tt0000005   NaN GreaterEuropean, British    GreaterEuropean, British    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I used replace and map function to get here.

[image: Another Look to Dataset]

I want to create a dataframe from the above data frames such as I can get resulting dataframe as below.

```
tconst  GreaterEuropean   WestEuropean   French  GreaterEuropean   British    Arab    British   ............
tt0000001   2   1   0   4   1   0   2 .....
tt0000002   0   2   4   0   1   3   0 .....
```

GreaterEuropean British WestEuropean Italian French ... represents number of ehnicities of different actors in a particlular movie specified by tconst.

That would be like a count matrix, such as for a movie tt00001 there are 5 Arabs, 2 British, 1 WestEuropean and so on such that in a movie, how many actors are there who belong to these ethnicities. 
Link to data - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oNfbTpmLA0imPieRxGfU_cBYVfWN3tZq

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mcve]. As an example, provide some code to create your dataframe (3 rows may suffice) and show what you want as output.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I also added link to the data and I have been various steps to reach here.

what pandas functionality I should use, I am stuck upon that.

Comment: I'm afraid a picture doesn't help. Have you read: [mcve]?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis I also added the data source in the link, which are basically 500 rows of the dataset, the original size is over 6 mn. I also added a resulting dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'tconst', 
                    value_vars = df.columns[2:].tolist(), 
                    var_name = 'actor', 
                    value_name = 'ethnicities').dropna()

print(df_melted.ethnicities.str.get_dummies(sep = ',').sum())
```

Output:

```
 British               169
 EastAsian               9
 EastEuropean           17
 French                 73
 Germanic                9
 GreaterEastAsian       13
 Hispanic                9
 IndianSubContinent      2
 Italian                 7
 Japanese                4
 Jewish                 25
 Nordic                  7
 WestEuropean          105
Asian                   15
GreaterEuropean        316
dtype: int64
```

This is close to what you wanted, but not exact. To get what you wanted, without typing out the lists of columns or values, is more complicated.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120674/6672746

```
def change_column_order(df, col_name, index):
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols.remove(col_name)
    cols.insert(index, col_name)
    return df[cols]

def split_df(dataframe, col_name, sep):
    orig_col_index = dataframe.columns.tolist().index(col_name)
    orig_index_name = dataframe.index.name
    orig_columns = dataframe.columns
    dataframe = dataframe.reset_index()  # we need a natural 0-based index for proper merge
    index_col_name = (set(dataframe.columns) - set(orig_columns)).pop()
    df_split = pd.DataFrame(
        pd.DataFrame(dataframe[col_name].str.split(sep).tolist())
        .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=1), columns=[col_name])
    df = dataframe.drop(col_name, axis=1)
    df = pd.merge(df, df_split, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='inner')
    df = df.set_index(index_col_name)
    df.index.name = orig_index_name
    # merge adds the column to the last place, so we need to move it back
    return change_column_order(df, col_name, orig_col_index)
```

Using those excellent functions:

```
df_final = split_df(df_melted, 'ethnicities', ',')
df_final.set_index(['tconst', 'actor'], inplace = True)
df_final.pivot_table(index = ['tconst'], 
                     columns = 'ethnicities', 
                     aggfunc = pd.Series.count).fillna(0).astype('int')
```

Output:

```
ethnicities     British     EastAsian   EastEuropean    French  Germanic    GreaterEastAsian    Hispanic    IndianSubContinent  Italian     Japanese    Jewish  Nordic  WestEuropean    Asian   GreaterEuropean
tconst                                                          
tt0000001   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   2
tt0000002   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
tt0000003   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   3
tt0000004   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1
tt0000005   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2
```

Comment: Although, I done it Evan. But I am really thankful you gave it and tried it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pandas have it all.

```
title_principals["all"] = title_principals["Actor1"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor2"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor3"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor4"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor5"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor6"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor7"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor8"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor9"].astype(str)+','+title_principals["Actor10"].astype(str)
```

and then, from the string, make the count and drop the other variables.

```
title_principals["GreaterEuropean"] = title_principals["all"].str.contains(r'GreaterEuropean').sum()
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this without typing all of the column names out... have not had a ton of luck so far.